# Change column values to column names without duplicate and append a list od values to each cell

Tags: python, pandas

I have a 400 rows long dataframe that looks something like this:

```
Name  Colour   Rating
V001  Blue      5
V001  Green     4
V001  Blue      5
V002  Red       2
V002  Yellow    6
V002  Yellow    5
V003  Blue      7
V003  Blue      1
V003  Green     2
```

What i want, is to convert values in Colour column to column names without duplicate, and append list of all values corresponding to that color. I also want to have only one row for one Name. New dataframe would look like this:

```
Name   Blue  Green  Red  Yellow
V001  [5,5]  [4]    []    []
V002  []     []     [2]   [6,5]
V003  [7,1]  [2]    []    []
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with replace missing values to empty `list`s:

```
df = df.pivot_table(index='Name', columns='Colour', values='Rating', aggfunc=list)
df = df.applymap(lambda x: [] if isinstance(x, float) else x)
print (df)
Colour    Blue Green  Red  Yellow
Name                             
V001    [5, 5]   [4]   []      []
V002        []    []  [2]  [6, 5]
V003    [7, 1]   [2]   []      []
```

For ranges is possible use:

```
for c in df.columns:
    for i in df.index:
        v = df.loc[i, c]
        #print (v)
        if len(v) > 1:
            print (range(v[1], v[0]))
```

Comment: can i apply a function which would return a range for each cell in dataframe? Something like df.applymap?

Comment: @Kuki - For you `applymap` not working? Can you be more specific about input/output ?

Comment: i am sure applymap is working but i don't know which function would return the range of list (cell) in dataframe.

Comment: @Kuki - Do you think `df = df.applymap(lambda x: print (x))` ?

Comment: I would like to have df that would show me the range for each cell. For example from my question...V001/Blue = [5,5] = 1 (range), V003/Blue = [7,1] = 6 (range)